# What is the best way of testing that, removing unused tables(migration) do not affect the application

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

We have some very old tables which we do not use. I am planning to remove those. My initial plan is to rename the tables and test if our application is affected anyway. But I am not sure how to test the application and make sure that it's not affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you should have tests for your application, which are going to break if anything is using the deleted tables.

Assuming that you don't have tests, the next best way is to run a global search in your codebase and look for those models / table names being used in the code. If you still don't feel confident, you can manually go through every page and make sure that nothing is broken. Depending on the size of your app, that might be really slow and painful, but it's what you get for not writing tests from the start :P

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Run all your automated tests. If you don't have any, right now is always the best time to start adding them.